# Should I put my interface definition in same namespace as its implementation

Tags: c#, interface

If I define an interface `ITestInterface` and then immediately create a class that implements that interface for usage within an application is it ok to keep the class and interface in the same namespace or should they be seperate. i.e. `Test.Interfaces` and `Test.Interfaces.Implementation`.

Both my interface and its implementation will be in its own assembly so I'm not looking to create another one just to contain the interface itself.

This is particular related to c# however I guess it can cover any language.

Comment: Test.Interfaces.Implementation seems kinda contradictory given that interfaces and implementations are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I wouldn't organize namespaces based on the type of thing they contain, but by their purpose.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's probably better to use the established conventions of the .NET predefined classes. For example, looking in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace we can see that both `IDictionary` and `Dictionary` are there. So probably putting them in the same namespace is the best idea.

Also, since both the interface and the implementation most likely serve the same purpose, it's better to group them in the same namespace.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the goal. Many of the answers here fall back on existing examples of MS libraries. That's fine, and it's not necessarily wrong, but MS has different objectives in creating those libraries than someone or some team might have in creating a business application.

If your goal is Dependency Inversion, for example as part of a [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), you would not have your interface and implementation in the same namespace.

See also: [SOLID Principles](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design).

Answer (score 3):

> This is particular related to c# however I guess it can cover any
>   language.

It's typical in Java to have the two in the same package.  The one exception I can think of might be a DAO interface in a package persistence and different implementations in subpackages under that (e.g. jdbc, hibernate, jdo, etc.)

You can think of a public interface as being the API that's exposed from the package.  I can see where implementation classes might be package private, preventing users from accessing the implementation via anything other than the interface.  Public factory methods would have to be provided to grant access.

Comment: Cheers.  That seems to agree with what @Tudor said about Microsofts practices as well.

Answer (score 3):

How about separate assemblies, same namespace?  I like it.

Comment: This can cause a problem when you add a reference the assembly containing the class that implements the interface. The compiler will throw an error if you do not have a reference to the assembly containing the interface. The caller is then left with the task of tracking down the assembly containing the interface.

Comment: I think the problem is the person adding the implementation assembly without the interface assembly.  You shouldn't necessarily design your Solutions based on what someone else might erroneously do with them.

Answer (score 2):

System.Collections.ArrayList implements System.Collections.IList. If Microsoft does it, why wouldn't you?

Comment: @Tim I fail to see your relevance. The question was where to put the interface, not wether it was needed at all.

Comment: Old answer, but my two cents. MS puts them in different namespace because MS intended to have multiple implementations in different assemblies, so they can be imported a la carte, or so uses can make their own.

If there is no intention to, (or sometimes a wish to discourage) extending the interface outside the package, this isn't a good reason to have them in different assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very abstract question. What is the reason for the interface? Is it a public API/framework or a simple application? Are you going to have multiple implementations of the same interface?

If the interfaces are in their own assemblies, then it is a good practice for the base namespaces to match the assembly names. But it sounds like you mean the class and the interface are in the same assembly.

Answer (score 1):

What is your intent?

If you wish to "hide" the implementation from the rest of your code and/or choose which of the several available implementations to "inject" at run-time, then your class should not be public anyway, so it doesn't really matter in which namespace it resides.

Otherwise, there is no problem for both interface and class residing in the same namespace.